# Jenkinsfile syntax - is there a DRY-example of shared python build steps?

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a repo "A" with shared python build scripts which I today run in various "Execute shell" build steps in Jenkins. I seed this steps/scripts from job-dsl groovy code.

Using the newer Jenkins 2 Pipeline-concept in a repo "B" (where my app source code resides) what must my Jenkinsfile in this repo look like to keep it DRY and reuse my existing python build scripts?

I have studied the plugin 'workflow-cps-global-lib' and I have tried to setup "Pipeline Libraries" on my Jenkins master but since this setup groovy-oriented it does not just feel like the right way to go or I just does not get hang of the correct syntax. I cannot find any examples on this specific use case.

Basically I just want to to this in my Jenkinsfile:

1. Clone my source repo ('B') for my app
2. Make my shared python build scripts from my repo "A" available
3. Execute the python build scripts from various "execute shell" steps
4. Etcetera...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[workflow-cps-global-lib](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin) is the way to go. Install it and setup in 'Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Pipeline Libraries to use your repository.

If you decided to use python scripts and not groovy, put all your python scripts in (root)/resources dir.

in your Jenkinsfile - load the script with `libraryResource`

```
script = libraryResource 'my_script.py'
```

and use it

```
sh script
```

Comment: how can you pass it arguments?

Comment: @red888 My solution to the problem was to do this: `script = script.replaceAll('sys\\.argv\\[1\\]', 'argument-goes-here')` Feels very hackish, but it works. It seems like it's the only option.

Comment: Dear God that's awful. It really does support args? I'm doing this with a ps1 and calling it with "powershell" similar to how you are. The way "sh" and "powershell" seem to leave no room for args?

Answer (score 1):

(not enough reputation to add comment to accepted answer above)

Given a python script in `/resources/myscript.py` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--echo")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.echo)
```

Use a Jenkins function like this:

```
def runPy(String scriptPath, def args) {
    String script = libraryResource(scriptPath)
    String argsString = args.join(' ')
    sh "python3 -c '${script}' ${argsString}"
}
runPy('myscript.py', ['--echo', 'foo'])
```